# App installs successfully but never passes the splash screen

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPad app which is currently in the testing phase.  I have deployed it (using TestFlight) to several employees of the company.

One of these employees is overseas and has zero knowledge about how Apple products, iPads and iPhones work and has never really sync's it.

When he installs the app using testflight (or using IPA drop) it installs successfully but when he runs the app - the splash screen loads and then the app immediately closes.  It remains in the list of open apps.

He is running iPad 2 GSM (4.3.5) and all the rest of the local employees are running iPad 2 Wi-Fi (5.0.1).

The base version of the app is set to 5.0 and deployment target 4.3.

How should I go about helping him - he is in a different country and I am not seeing any crash logs in TestFlight and I don't have physical access to his device.

Comment: sorry if this is a dumb/obvious question, but have you had him hard-reboot his device? I've had app installs fail to run until I rebooted the device.

Comment: Will double check he has tried rebooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run you app in iPad 4.3 Simulator. Maybe you are using features available only in iOS 5.

If he can connect iPad and complete sync with iTunes, then you may as him to look up for crash logs in filesystem of computer. More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already integrated the TestFlight SDK, you could look at using their checkpoint API to effectively trace through the application execution and determine where/why it's failing.

The other thing to look at is whether the app is taking too long to startup and is being killed by the watchdog timer.

Comment: I have a checkpoint at applicationDidFinishLoading which the app never hits